# Alternate Element to show jQuery Validation errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can one show all the validation errors in a separate element (ex: `div`) instead of using the labels attached to each of the elements?

Currently I have the following code that is binding all the errors to another `div` element below the form.

```
$('#myForm').validate({
        rules:{
            txtName:{
                required:true,
                minlength:5,
                maxlength:100
            },
            selGroups:{
                required:true
            },
            txtDate:{
                required:true
            }
        },
        submitHandler:function () {
            return false;
        },
        messages:{
            txtHolidayName:"Please enter the Name (5 - 100 chars)",
            selGroups:"Please select the Group",
            txtHolidayDate:"Please select the date"
        },
        errorPlacement:function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo($('#errorContainer'));
        },
        invalidHandler:function (form, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors)
                $('#errorContainer').fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

I have partially achieved this, but having trouble hiding the `div` element which contains all the errors after the success of all validations. Could someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the **errorLabelContainer** setting, which works nicely with the wrapper setting also

```
$("form").validate({
errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
wrapper: "li",
});
```

make sure you have the corresponding html

```
<ul id="messageBox"></ul>
<form>
 <input name="fname" id="fname" class="required">
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't seem to find this option on the documentation. `http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation`. Do you where I could look at the option that you have specified?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions search for errorLabelContainer